# Вывести все страницы с определенной меткой

Tags: php, wordpress

Собственно заголовок и есть вопрос, 
я делаю вот так, но он выводит просто все страницы вообще.

```
<?php $news = new WP_query('tag=92'); $news->query(array('post_type' => page')); ?>
<?php while ($news->have_posts()) : $news->the_post(); ?>
<div class="last_new">      
    <div class="last_new_img">  
        <?php echo raft_post_img_wp($post->ID, 0, 1, 'img290'); ?>
        <div class="last_new_data"><?php the_time('j.m.Y') ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="last_new_zag"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неверно задаете аргументы WP_Query. Смотрите [документацию](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters)

```
$news= new WP_Query( array( 'tag_id' => 92 ) );
```

Comment: так я пробовал, нечего не меняется

Comment: 'post_type' => page , разве у страниц есть метки?

Comment: Большое спасибо pavel я когда делал так как вы показали я после id пробел случайно поставил)) да теги я сам написал для страниц